# How do I continue the running totals computation from union selects in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries joined using Union All. The first computes the opening balance and the second returns rows of columns. I need to have the computed balance from the first query carry over to the second query.

Here's my table:

```
ItemTrans
id    ItemNo    InQty    OutQty   DateAdded   
100   'A001'    0        100      '2020-12-20'
101   'A002'    600      0        '2020-12-20'
102   'A001'    500      0        '2020-12-21'
103   'A002'    0        110      '2020-12-20'
104   'A002'    0        75       '2020-12-20'
105   'A001'    0        50       '2020-12-22'
106   'A001'    10       0        '2021-01-05'
107   'A001'    0        20       '2021-01-06'
108   'A001'    0        10       '2021-01-07'
109   'A001'    0        10       '2021-01-08'
```

Here's my query:

```
Select 
  'Opening bal' as 'IDNo',
  '' as ItemNo,
  '2020-12-31' as 'Date Posted/ As of',
  0 as QTY,
  Balance = (sum(InQty) - sum(OutQty)) 
  From itemTrans
  Where ItemNo = 'A001'
  AND DateAdded < '2021-01-01'
Union All
Select 
  cast(id as nvarchar(20)) as 'IDNo',
  ItemNo,
  DateAdded as 'Date Posted/ As of',
  QTY = InQty - OutQty,
  Case
    When InQty > 0 Then sum(InQty) OVER (ORDER BY id)
    When OutQty > 0 Then sum(OutQty*-1) OVER (ORDER BY id)
    else 0
  End as Balance
  From ItemTrans
  Where ItemNo = 'A001'
  AND DateAdded >= '2021-01-01'
```

My query needs to return the following:

```
IDNo           ItemNo    Date Posted/ As of    QTY    Balance
Opening bal              2020-12-31            0      350
106            A001      2021-01-05            10     360
107            A001      2021-01-06            -20    340
108            A001      2021-01-07            -10    330
109            A001      2021-01-08            -10    210
```

But my query returns:

```
IDNo           ItemNo    Date Posted/ As of    QTY    Balance
Opening bal              2020-12-31            0      350
106            A001      2021-01-05            10     10
107            A001      2021-01-06            -20    -20
108            A001      2021-01-07            -10    -30
109            A001      2021-01-08            -10    -40
```

It also seems that the running InQty is computed separately from the OutQty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Each part of the query stands on its own, and the running sum is calculated only on that part. You need to subquery it, and make sure that it is all ordered correctly:

```sql
SELECT
  IDNo,
  ItemNo,
  [Date Posted/ As of],
  QTY,
  Case
    When InQty > 0 Then sum(InQty) OVER (ORDER BY ordering, id)
    When OutQty > 0 Then sum(OutQty*-1) OVER (ORDER BY ordering, id)
    else 0
  End AS Balance
FROM (
    Select 
      0 as id,
      0 as ordering,
      'Opening bal' as IDNo,
      '' as ItemNo,
      '2020-12-31' as [Date Posted/ As of],
      0 as QTY,
      AddBalance = (sum(InQty) - sum(OutQty)),
      sum(InQty) InQty,
      sum(OutQty) OutQty
    From itemTrans
    Where ItemNo = 'A001'
      AND DateAdded < '2021-01-01'
    Union All
    Select 
      id,
      1,
      cast(id as nvarchar(20)),
      ItemNo,
      DateAdded,
      InQty - OutQty,
      0,
      InQty,
      OutQty
    From ItemTrans
    Where ItemNo = 'A001'
      AND DateAdded >= '2021-01-01'
) t
```

Use `[]` not `''` to quote column names with spaces.

Comment: Hi, I tried running the query but ran into errors Invalid column name 'InQty', Invalid column name 'OutQty'. These are on the outer query

Comment: Sorry fixed now

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, didn't get the desired results. The opening balance has 500 instead of 350. but on the next  row, the balance updated  to 510. The third row computed a balance of -170. The last two rows have -180 and -190.  I'll edit your answer to show the results. I'll check your code further. Much appreciated on your assistance :-)

Comment: I guess let's not be sloppy. I've put in a fixed ordering column now

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, I made some adjustments to your code and it worked. If okay with you, I'd like to edit your answer and paste in the working code. I'd replace your code. Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from the previous answer, I came up with the query below that gave me the results I needed.

```
SELECT
  IDNo,
  ItemNo,
  [Date Posted/ As of],
  QTY,
  sum(Balance) OVER (ORDER BY id) as Balance
FROM 
(
  Select 
  0 as id,
  'Opening bal' as IDNo,
  '' as ItemNo,
  '2020-12-31' as [Date Posted/ As of],
  0 as QTY,
  Balance = (sum(InQty) - sum(OutQty))
  From itemTrans
  Where ItemNo = 'A001'
    AND DateAdded < '2021-01-01'
Union All
  Select 
    id,
    cast(id as nvarchar(20)) as IDNo,
    ItemNo,
    DateAdded as [Date Posted/ As of],
    InQty - OutQty,
    InQty - OutQty as Balance
  From ItemTrans
  Where ItemNo = 'A001'
    AND DateAdded >= '2021-01-01'
)t
```